I have to capture the previous and current value of an lightning selected and enable or disable the fields based on that in aura
<lightning:select name="Ordering Type" label="Ordering Type" required="true" aura:id="posInventorySeasonalId"  disabled="{!and(v.posItem.Inventory_Seasonal_Program__c != 'Seasonal Program', not(empty(v.posItem.Id)))}" onchange="{!c.validateInventorySeasonal}" value="{!v.posItem.Inventory_Seasonal_Program__c}" messageWhenValueMissing="Please select an option from the list.">
 <option class="option_style" text="Select" value="" />
 <option text="Both" value="Both" />
 <option text="Seasonal Program" value="Seasonal Program" />
 <option text="Inventory" value="Inventory" />
 </lightning:select>

<lightning:input name="packOf" required="true" value="{!v.posItem.Pack_Of__c}" label="Pack Of" aura:id="posItemPackOfInputField" onchange="{!c.validatePosItemPackOf}" maxlength="3" messageWhenValueMissing="Please enter a suitable value."  disabled="{!and(v.posItem.Inventory_Seasonal_Program__c != 'Seasonal Program', not(empty(v.posItem.Id)))}" />

Above is the cmp file
On editing let's say my current value is Seasonal Program , I am changing it to Inventory
When I do this I want to enable the Pack of. But When the current value is Inventory . Pack of should remain disabled
How to achieve this in aura
Please somebody help me to solve this
Thanks in advance
I tried using boolean variable but it enables for both the condition or disables for both the condition please help me to solve
